# How can i verify the logdatetime of the nightshift employees

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a Log Monitoring for employees and i encounter that when an employee is on a nightshift eg. 10PM and when she log his/her id it stores in the database and in later night around 1 AM (next day), he/she accidentally login herself to the system so we have a double data of his/her login.

I have a query here on checking of Logs, if the user have an existing record within the day starting 00:00:00 time, the system wont accept any data.

```
SELECT `UserIdx`
from tbl_Logs
where `UserIdx` = p_UserIdx
and `DateTime` between current_date()+ '00:00:00' and current_timestamp()
```

How can i check the log data from another day and verify it if its duplicate?

Comment: The best practice is to capture a logout time as well. But, if that is not possible in your case, a workaround approach is to divide your day based on shifts rather than 0000 hrs midnight. So, if a person has multiple log-ins between shift start and shift end, you would know which timestamps to consider.

Comment: I don't understand your question at all.  You say "the system won't accept any data".  However, your code is just a `select` statement and that has nothing to do with what data gets stored into the database.  You might want to ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: What i mean is before inserting data , i need to select data . If it exist, the system wont accept data but if the time changes, data can be accepted again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below script.

```
SELECT `UserIdx`
from tbl_Logs
where `UserIdx` = p_UserIdx
and `DateTime` between DATE_ADD(curdate(),interval 0 second) and current_timestamp()
```